# Logging out from Identity after cookie has expired causes http error 400

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

In my `_LoginPartial.cshtml` I have this logout-button:

```
<form id="logoutForm" class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "", new { area = "" })">
    <button id="logout" type="submit">
        Log out
    </button>
</form>
```

Then, from what I can gather, `Logout.cshtml.cs` is called:

```
public class LogoutModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LogoutModel> _logger;

    public LogoutModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<LogoutModel> logger)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
        if (returnUrl != null)
        {
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToPage();
        }
    }
}
```

But if the user session cookie has expired when the user presses "Log out", I get this descriptive error message:

> HTTP ERROR 400

Any breakpoints set anywhere in `Logout.cshtml.cs` is never hit.

What is happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> if the user session cookie has expired when the user presses "Log out", I get this descriptive error message:
>
> HTTP ERROR 400
>
> Any breakpoints set anywhere in Logout.cshtml.cs is never hit.

As we know, Razor Pages are protected from XSRF/CSRF automatically. And the antiforgery token (associated with the current user's identity) that client user sent to server would cause verification fail if current user's authentication expired, which cause above error.

To fix above error, you can apply `IgnoreAntiforgeryToken` Attribute to LogoutModel class, like below.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public class LogoutModel : PageModel
{
```

You can get detailed information about "Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF/CSRF) attacks" from following doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Are there any security concerns about ignoring the anti forgery token if used like this?

Comment: Normally, disabling antiforgery token validation is not recommended. But for the scenario in this thread, applying it to Logout endpoint is fine.

Comment: I ended up having to add this to the login model too.